# Calculating four in a row in a list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The user rolls five dice. If four of these are in a row then the user is awarded 30 points, if not then they are awarded no points. When i have my list of 5 numbers to represent dice, how am i able to search through that list to see if it contains four numbers in a row? My code at the moment is as follows:

```
diceList = sorted(diceList)
elif letterChoice == "J" and diceCombinations[9] == False:
    diceList = list(set(diceList))
    print (diceList)
    if diceList in [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6]]:
        score = score + 30
        diceCombinations[9] = True
```

This works for the most part but falls short if i roll a 1,2,3,4,6 for example. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse your `in` test using `any`, and keep `diceList` as a `set`:

```
diceList = set(diceList)
if any(match <= diceList for match in (
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {2, 3, 4, 5},
        {3, 4, 5, 6},
    )):
    # do something
```

Explanation:

`set`s only keep one copy of a unique element, so `{1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 6}` ends up being `{1, 3, 6, 2}`  (order is not preserved), so by casting `diceList` to a set we lose any duplicates.

Then we iterate through the possible solutions of "four in a row", such as `{1, 2, 3, 4}` to see if `diceList` is a match.  That part works by using the `<=` notation, which for `set`s means does the LHS (left-hand side) have fewer elements than the RHS (right-hand side), (`<`) or the same elements as the RHS (`=`), and no elements not present in the RHS.  So:

- `{1, 2}` is `<` `{1, 2, 3}`.
- `{1, 2, 3}` is `=` `{1, 2, 3}`
- `{1, 2, 5}` is not `<` nor `=` to `{1, 2, 3}`

Note: this is known as partial ordering because it is possible for one `set` to not be `=`, not be `<`, and not be `>` another `set`.

Comment: I believe you could save a little work by changing `row & diceList == row` to just `row <= diceList`, which does proper subset checking (with short-circuiting) without needing to create a temporary `set` and perform a comparison.

Comment: @ShadowRanger:  Yup, tested and it works; updated my code.  Thanks!

Comment: "keep diceList as a set" - kind of confusing, name-wise.

Comment: @AustinHastings: I had no input in either the name of the variable in the OP's question, nor the name of the data type in Python.  ;)

Comment: This might fail what the OP wants. If OP wants 4 numbers in consecutive order. Or 4 numbers that are consecutive but can be in any order. And I believe it should be the former. Eg ( `diceList = [ 2, 4, 1, 3, 6]` should fail ). Although the order is lost with `diceList = sorted(diceList)` and `diceList = list(set(diceList))`

Comment: @StevenSummers: `diceList` is representative of rolling five dice; in every dice game I have played the dice do not have to line up in the correct order, they just have to be there.  Also, the OP sorted the `diceList` as his first step.